# Microsoft Word Highlighting Text White

Tags: macos, textbox, ms-word

For some reason, whenever I create a Text Box and start typing, the background text is highlighted white and I can't make it transparent. This picture should explain everything:
[image: Example of text in textbox having white highlight]

I want to remove the highlighting so the gradient in the background shows through. I used to do things like this a lot, but for some reason Word won't let me now. Any suggestions?

I am on Word 2011 Mac

Comment: If you can set a custom color (code) for the background, then type 000000 (black/transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the text box that you want to make invisible.

1. If you want to change multiple text boxes, click the first text box or shape, and then press and hold SHIFT while you click the other text boxes.
2. On the shortcut menu, click Format Text Box.
3. On the Colors and Lines tab, in the Fill section, click the arrow next to Color, and then click No Color.
4. On the Colors and Lines tab, in the Line section, click the arrow next to Color, and then click No Color.
5. Click OK.  Your textbox's background is now *invisible...*

It seems the actual text highlight is your problem, so try:

- Go into Borders and Shading, apply it to text, and set it to clear. Had me confused because I've never had to do this before.

As seen [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/make-the-background-of-a-text-box-invisible-HA010337242.aspx#BMword).

Comment: I've searched on google a lot for this and wouldn't be asking a question here if I could find it in 30 seconds. Thanks tho.  Here's a picture that'll probably make my problem more understandable: http://pbrd.co/1dSukS7

Comment: It's the text that's being highlighted, not the textbox itself.

Comment: Ok I found the answer, turns out I had to go into borders and shading, apply it to text, and set it to clear. Had me confused because I've never had to do this before. Thanks for the response anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Got some clues here and finally found a solution for MSWord for Mac version 16.9:

- Select the text you want to fix
- Select "Design" Tab
- Click "Page Borders"
- Click the "Shading" Tab
- Select Apply to "Text"
- [Fill] is showing "No Color". Open the selection and re-select "No Color"
- Hit "OK"

Worked for me. It is obviously a bug in Word.

Comment: Not working for me, `No Color` property for `Text` is not applying.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched around and had trouble finding this.

In Word for Mac 2011

1. Highlight the text
2. Click tables in the ribbon
3. Find the shading icon (looks like a paint bucket)
4. Click the down arrow next to the bucket and select `No Fill`

Answer (score 0):

Change the text format from anything apart from **Normal text.***(important)*

Solution 1

- Select the Text box and go to the **"format"** tab,
- modify the outline and fill options

if this isn't enough

Solution 2

- select the Text box and right click for options
- select the last option **"format shape"**